# Setting default permissions for all new dirs/files in a dir and its subdirs, no matter who creates them

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chmod, acl

I have a directory, and I want all directories created in this directory, or its sub dirs, to be 777 and all files created in it or any of its subdirectories to be 666. It doesn't matter which user creates these files and dirs, I always want them to have those permissions by default.

I have tried to achive this with ACL but I am failing:

```
setfacl -R -d -m o::rw /home/test
```

For some reason, this makes the new files to be rw-r-r instead of rw-rw-rw.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: I don't understand ACLs much, but what is a default ACL good for if it does not override umask?